# Export data frame to SQL server using RODBC package

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, rodbc

I am using `RODBC` package in R to import / export data frames from SQL Server database. While there is no problem in importing. I dont know how to export the contents of a data frame into an existing SQL table.

I am trying to use `sqlQuery()` function available in the package, but I am not sure how to insert multiple records in the table.

A sample  on how to insert the rows will be helpful
I have ensured that columns of my table and data frame are same.

Answer (score 4):

Use `sqlSave` with append property. See my code below:

```
 sqlSave(uploaddbconnection, outputframe, tablename =
    "your_TableName",rownames=FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my code on using `sqlSave()`. I am using SQL Server 2008. `Conn` is a connection that I created using `odbcConnect()`:

```
#creating data to be saved in SQL Table
data_to_save<-cbind(scenario_1,scenario_2,scenario_3,scenario_4,store_num,future_date,Province,index)

#use sqlSave() rather than sqlQuery() for saving data into SQL Server
sqlSave(conn,data.frame(data_to_save),"CC_Forecast",safer=FALSE,append=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks Yan. I know this function, but it throws out error in case of fairly big data frame. `sqlQuery()` is a more general function which inserts data frame row by row, Also `sqlSave()` doesn't work if your data frame columns are subset of your table

Answer (score 1):

```
dbWriteTable(conn, "RESULTS", results2000, append = T)
```

use DBI package

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add upon Yan's answer.

Before you use sqlSave() function, make sure you change your default database to  the right database where your table are. Especially if you want to write to an existing table!

[See here:](https://andersspur.wordpress.com/2013/11/26/connect-r-to-sql-server-2012-and-14/) for how to set up ODBC connection and how to change default database.

After that, you can use these to dump data to sql:

```
specificDB= odbcConnect(dsn ='name you set up in ODBC',uid = '***', pwd = '****')

sqlSave(specificDB, output_to_sql, tablename = 'a_table_in_specificDB', rownames = F,append = T)

close(specificDB)
```

It is slow. be patient.