# Joining two dataframes with sqldf results in NA Column

Tags: sql, r, join

I am trying to join two data frames using the sqldf package.

These are reproducible examples of my two dataframes:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
c <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
d <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
e <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

dataframe1 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)

a <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,5)
b <- c(NA,NA,NA,4,NA)
c <- c(NA,NA,3,NA,NA)
d <- c(NA,2,NA,NA,NA)
e <- c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA)
f <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

dataframe2 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

This is a reproducible example of the join on the dataframes:

```
final_data <- sqldf("SELECT *
                     FROM dataframe1
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN dataframe2 USING(a,b,c,d,e)")
```

The resulting f column in final_data which is introduced via the join is filled with NAs. Why? The ideal f column would have the corresponding values for a,b,c,d, and e that exist in dataframe2. How could I solve this?

Comment: There are no matching rows between the two data frames, so the result is `dataframe1` with all NULL (`NULL` in SQL, `NA` in R) values in the new `f` column. If you want values in the `f` column you'd need at least one row where all of `a, b, c, d, e` match between the data frames.

Comment: Is there no way to exclude the NAs in my join and only insert the value that corresponds to the shared value in each row in dataframe2?  The merge() function in R sort of does that with the argument "incompatibles = NA", but this only works when joining on one column and I am joining on 5.

Comment: Perhaps I could specify in my join to join the common column on (a OR b OR c OR d OR e) so that it only joins when it matches on one of the values. How could I put that in sql?

Comment: Or maybe a custom function to do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `OR` criteria, the corresponding SQL is

```
SELECT *
FROM dataframe1 d1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dataframe2 d2
ON (
  d1.a = d2.a
  OR d1.b = d2.b
  OR d1.c = d2.c
  OR d1.d = d2.d
  OR d1.e = d2.e
)
```

Since the column values from `df1` aren't necessarily equal to those from `df2`, you get a copy from each of them. If you only want to retain the values from `df1` as well as `f` from `df2`, then do this:

```
SELECT d1.*, d2.f
FROM dataframe1 d1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dataframe2 d2
ON (
  d1.a = d2.a
  OR d1.b = d2.b
  OR d1.c = d2.c
  OR d1.d = d2.d
  OR d1.e = d2.e
)
```

The R join functions I know about (`merge`, `plyr::join` and `dplyr::left_join`) all require all of the columns in the join to be equal, though you could pretty easily hack together a custom function that joins one at a time and then `coalesce`s the results.

Comment: this works. Thanks Gregor. I didn't know the library accepted completely native sql.

Comment: It literally creates a SQL database, imports any data frames you use, executes your SQL, and exports the result back to R.

Comment: Interesting - this is a different question but do you know if there is any r package to import dataframes into a sql database as tables?

Comment: aha this is a common request! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302514/export-data-frame-to-sql-server-using-rodbc-package

Comment: RODBC is a good one, there are also many DB-specific packages. See pretty much anything in the "reverse depends" list [of the DBI package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/DBI/). Many of the "reverse imports" too.

Comment: With sqldf this stores the BOD data.frame in the mydb database (creating the database if it does not exist): `sqldf(c("attach mydb as new", "create table new.BOD as select * from BOD"))`   ; however, typically one would use the RSQLite package directly for this.